# Why does java reflection shows object method as instance's one, not static?

Tags: java, scala, program-entry-point

Default java console application runs passed class with the `main` method that should be declared with *static* modifier.

So, I've tried to create such class as object instead of directly using static modifier. But surprisingly I got main method without static modifier.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3-20130923-000000-e2fec6b28d (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

scala> object Main {
     | def main(args : Array[String]) = println("hello")
     | }
defined module Main

scala> val method = Main.getClass.getMethod("main", classOf[Array[String]])
method: java.lang.reflect.Method = public void Main$.main(java.lang.String[])

scala> Modifier.isStatic( method.getModifiers )
res0: Boolean = false
```

So `Main` object contains `main` method that is not actually static.

I'd like to use `java` command for running scala classes rather that specific `scala` command.

How can I get static  main method out of scala object?

---

#### update:

It was suggested to search for a class with the same name except it does not have '$' symbol as suffix. So, I continued REPL session trying to find this class

```
scala> val loader = Main.getClass.getClassLoader
loader: ClassLoader = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@fdf3a48

scala> val mc = Class.forName("Main", true, loader)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:69)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:756)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:774)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:713)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:577)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:878)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

I may suppose that I need to call special function from scala compiler utils to get wrapper for a defined class

---

#### solved:

I made more experiments and confirmed that scalac behavior differs from scala REPL. The first generates additional class for every object and that class have object's methods as static. If you create a class and his companion object than companion's methods would be added to the associated class without creating additional proxy. This works for any method, even those methods which signature differs from the main method signature

Comment: Googling "scala static method" lifts all ambiguities: Scala does not have static. The equivalent of a Java static method is a function in an object.

Comment: @vptheron ... and op expects object method to be static one, but reflection says the opposite.

Comment: the last error is only related to usage of REPL: classes defined in it are getting wrapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala compiler does create a static main method:

```
$ cat Main.scala 
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("hello")
}
$ scalac Main.scala
$ ls *class
Main.class  Main$.class
$ javap -cp . Main
Compiled from "Main.scala"
public final class Main {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
$ javap -cp . Main$
Compiled from "Main.scala"
public final class Main$ {
  public static final Main$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
$ java -cp /usr/local/scala/lib/scala-library.jar:. Main
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decompile this:

```
package test
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val method = Main.getClass.getMethod("main", classOf[Array[String]])
    println(Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers)) // false

    println(Main.getClass.getName()); // test.Main$

    val act = Class.forName("test.Main");
    val method2 = act.getMethod("main", classOf[Array[String]])
    println(Modifier.isStatic(method2.getModifiers)) // true !!!
  }
}
```

you will see two classes:

1)

```
public final class Main$
{
  ...
  public void main(String[] args)
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

2)

```
public final class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will remove this answer as soon as real one showups, but it's not that scala doesn't have static method, the problem is the [wrong?] use of java reflection for such inspection:

```
/tmp » echo 'object Main {  def main(args : Array[String]) = println("hello") }' > Main.scala
/tmp » scalac Main.scala
/tmp » javap Main      
Compiled from "Main.scala"
public final class Main {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```